# how to force linux to allocate memory in high (64bit) address space

Tags: linux, memory-management, 64-bit

I'm trying to track down a segfault problem in an old C code (not written by me). The segfaults occur only, if the addresses of certain variables in that code exceed the 32bit integer limit. (So I've got a pretty good idea what's going wrong, but I don't know where.)

So, my question is: Is there any way to force linux to allocate memory for a process in the high address space? At the moment it's pretty much down to chance whether the segfault happen, which makes debugging a bit difficult.

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04, Kernel 2.6.31-23-generic on a Dell inspiron 1525 laptop with 2GB ram, if that's any help.

Thanks in advance,
Martin.

Comment: Have you tried [valgrinding](http://www.valgrind.org) the problem first?

Answer (score 2):

You can allocate an anonymous block of memory with the `mmap()` system call, which you can pass as an argument where you want it to be mapped.

Answer (score 0):

I would turn on the `-Wpointer-to-int-cast` and `-Wint-to-pointer-cast` warning options and check out any warnings they turn up (I believe these are included in `-Wall` on 64-bit targets). The cause is very likely something related to this, and simply auditing the warnings the compiler turns up may be a better approach than using a debugger.